# Searching multiple numbers in txt and changing variables

Tags: windows, batch-file, set, findstr, txt

Hey I'm trying to create a batch that allows me to find numbers in a .txt file and change a variable with it when it's existing.

When the number is existing, it Should change this "██" from Red to Green.

In the .txt file it looks like this:

```
Region1=1
Region1=82
Region1=55
Region3=39
Region5=2
Region2=36
Region4=36
Region6=43
Ect...
```

I have a combination of "Region(1-6) and colors (1-100)(201-226)"
This is what I tried:

```
@Echo off
chcp 65001

Set SAAC1=[40;31m
Set SAAC2=[40;31m
Set SAAC3=[40;31m
Set SAAC4=[40;31m
REM ......
Set SAAC226=[40;31m


:SearchColor1
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('findstr /I /E "Region1=1" %appdata%\Batch\Colors.txt') do set 
"SearchColor=%%a"
if '%SearchColor%'=='1' GOTO ColorExists1
goto ColorSearch2


:ColorExist1
cls
Set SAAC1=[40;32m
goto SearchColor2


:SearchColor2
REM ..... Region[1-6]=[1-226]



:End
cls
Echo  %SAAC1%██[40;37m   1  Red
Echo.
Echo  %SAAC2%██[40;37m   2  Blue
Echo.
Echo  %SAAC3%██[40;37m   3  Green
Echo.
Echo   %SAAC4%██[40;37m  4  Yellow
Echo.
REM  .......
Echo  %SAAC226%██[40;37m  226 Slate Dye¹
```

It could probably work, but I would have to search for every single Region and Color number.

I Hope someone can help me with it. :)

The picture shows how it looks like right now.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ei39x.png)

Comment: You may wish to revisit your code, because there appears to be formatting/or syntax issues with it. For example two individual commands ```do set ``` and then ```"SearchColor=%%a"``` is probably not you intended to do.

Comment: beyond what compo has already stated regarding invalid syntax, what is the use case / end goal. IE the reason for reading the value from a file and converting said value to a given color value.  From your picture I'm assuming it's an inventory of sorts and you wish to  change the red marker beside each string to green if a color is owned / available. Can you confirm?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm it.
If I take Region1=82 for example, then 82 would be the color.
I want to check if 82 is in my .txt
if it's available, I want to change the red marker to green.

Answer (score 0):

something along these lines should suffice

```bat
@Echo off & CD "%~dp0"
Mode 152,40
CHCP 65001 > nul
For /F %%a in ('Echo prompt $E^|cmd')Do Set "\E=%%a"

Setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

(
 For /L %%i in (1 1 100)Do ( findstr /ELIC:"=%%i" "%appdata%\Batch\Colors.txt" && Set "SAAC%%i=%\E%[7;32m" || Set "SAAC%%i=%\E%[7;31m" )
 For /L %%i in (201 1 226)Do ( findstr /LIC:"=%%i" "%appdata%\Batch\Colors.txt" && Set "SAAC%%i=%\E%[7;32m" || Set "SAAC%%i=%\E%[7;31m" )
) > Nul 2> nul

 Echo(%\E%[2J%\E%[0;33m%\E%[?25l-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Echo(%\E%[2;67H%\E%[0;33mFerox%\E%[0m
 Echo(%\E%[0;33m-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Echo(%\E%[4;2H!SAAC1!  %\E%[0;33m  1  Red %\E%[4;32H!SAAC27!  %\E%[0;33m 27  Dino Dark Green %\E%[4;62H !SAAC53!  %\E%[0;33m 53  Dino Medium Blue %\E%[4;92H !SAAC79!  %\E%[0;33m 79  Actual Black %\E%[4;122H !SAAC205!  %\E%[0;33m 205 Forrest Dye¹%\E%[0m%\E%[?25h

:# continue displaying each line of output below
```

Output with regions in colors.txt having values 27 and 205
[image]

Comment: [see this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) for information related to virtual terminal code usage with regards to cursor positioning, screen clearing and cursor hiding used in the above.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! :D
Took me a while to understand it.
Seems to be not working perfectly, because 11 will be also identified as 1 but findstr /E seems to fix it.

Thanks again !